# PWM with PNP circuit

Tags: pwm, pnp

Does anybody know the function of the PNP circuit?

The PWM is UC3843 output, and then connected this PNP circuit.

Can anyone tell me how it works?

[image]

Comment: @Transistor What is transistor destroyer?

Comment: If Vout is connected to a power supply then turning on the transistor will cause it to short between the PSU positive and negative causing high current to flow, overheat the transistor and burn it out. That portion of the circuit on its own is useless. You need to [edit] to give some context about the circuit and where you found it.

Comment: @Transistor I edit my circuit

Comment: Where is gate-source capacitance. It holds some charge and makes MOSFET turn off slowly. To make it faster BJT  discharge it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a kind of forced discharge  of the gate capacitance. Usually there is a diode instead of the resistor. But will work with the right resistor for the right gate cap.

Comment: Can you tell me how it works in detail ?

Comment: @Jitter456 Do you know how a PNP works, in detail? What happens when there's a voltage on Vout, (so the NMOS is switched ON) and then the PWM signal turns LOW (0 V), what will the PNP do?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I don't understand why the PNP would turn on the E point voltage is the same with B point why the PNP would turn on

Comment: @Jitter456 What is "B and E point?" Perhaps you mean **Base** and **Emitter**? Who says that the Base and Emitter are at the same voltage immediately after the PWM signal turns LOW (0 V)? Realize that the N-channel MOSFET has a large gate **capacitance** between Gate and Source.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie You mean when the PWM signal turns LOW because the Cgs has high voltage than PWM signal so the PNP would turn on and make the Cgs discharge quickly ?

Comment: @Jitter456 You got it! The same could be done with a diode (same as disconnecting the collector of that PNP) but then all the current from the Cgs capacitor has to flow through  the PWM input. By using a PNP like this most of the current will flow through the Emitter - Collector of the PNP and only 1/100th of the current is provided by the PWM input. (I'm assuming the PNP has a \$\beta\$ of 100).

Answer (score 0):

When turning the MOSFET on, the PWM driver drives the gate directly, charging the gate capacitance via the 10 ohm resistor.

When turning the MOSFET off, the same initially happens, But when the voltage across the 10 ohm resistor reaches Vbe, the PNP turns on, draining the gate charge faster to turn the MOSFET off faster, increasing dI/dt and thus the potential output voltage.

Comment: I got it, thanks